# Automatic overflow check in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, modulo, integer-overflow

Consider a matrix multiplication in Python where the input matrices A and B have quite large elements of `np.int64` precision. After the multiplication I am taking the remainder modulo F. For simplicity consider the following product of two matrices:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

A = [[2251875000001, 0]]
B = [[28839630, 0]]

A_mat = np.matrix(A,dtype=object)
A_mat = A_mat.transpose()

B_mat = np.matrix(B,dtype=object)

F = 33232924804801

C = np.dot(A_mat, B_mat)%F

C_mat = np.concatenate(C).astype(np.int64)
```

The matrices I am working with and their values are quite larger than that. I am not getting any warning and the code seems to work fine. However, I am wondering whether there are precision errors or overflows that are not detected by default. Is there any way to perform a special check during the execution for such behavior or just exit?

Comment: The largest number that can fit into a 64bit int is a LOT larger than the numbers you're working with... however, if there are overflows, I assume numpy will warn you.

Comment: *"...if there are overflows, I assume numpy will warn you."* Actually it doesn't.  For example, `np.array(2**63-1).dot(2)` returns -2 with no warning.

Comment: related? https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4126

Comment: If your computational resources allow you could perform the same operation with floating point precision and check if both results are "similar enough". (This won't guarantee that no overflow occurs, but increase the chance of noticing one...)